# Keeping Checkbox checked if id exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my code below, when i select a checkbox it displays the name of the item checked. But my problem now is, the table is paginated so when i move to the next page and return, the already checked item goes back unchecked. 
The same applies when i check a box and filter using the ajax request, when i return the already checked box will have moved to unchecked state.

Why is this happening and how can i resolve this issue ?

**HTML**

```
<table class="table" id="table" style="background-color:white" >
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th colspan="5"></th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      @foreach($items as $item) 
      <tr>
         <td><input onclick="return results(this)" data-item="{{$item->toJson()}}" type="checkbox" id="{!! $item->id !!}" name="{!! $item->name !!}" value="{!! $item->price !!}" /> </td>
         <td>{{$item->name }}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach       
   </tbody>
</table>
{{$items->links()}}
```

**JS**

```
function results(item){   
    var major = JSON.parse(item.dataset.item);
    if(item.checked == true)  {
     $('.panel').append(
        '<div class="container "> '+ 
        '<table style="width:100%;" class="table" id="tables">'+
        '<thead>'+'<thead>'+
        '<tbody>'+
         '<tr>'+ '<td  class="name" >'+major.name+'</td>'+] '</tr>'+
       '</tbody>'+'</table>'+'</div>')}
     } else {
     });
  }           
}
}
```

**AJAX**

```
success: function (data) {
   console.log(data);
   $("#table").slideDown('fast');
   var table = $("#table tbody");
   table.html("");
   $.each(data, function(idx, elem){
        table.append(
            "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' onclick='return results(this)' data-item='"+JSON.stringify(elem)+"' id='"+elem.id+"' name='"+elem.name+"' value='"+elem.price+"'  data-id="+elem.id+"  /></td><td >"+elem.name+"</td><tr>"
        );           
    });
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're replacing the page when the page is changed. You could probably cache the current page when you switch to another page, and when you're loading a page you check if it exists in the cache and only fetch from the server if it doesn't

Comment: @H77, how do i go about that? I don't really have an idea of what you are talking about

Comment: If your application is a SPA i.e on pagination complete page load does not happen, you can save your check box states saved in some JS variable and use it once you are back on a particular page. JS variable has to be available across the navigation. If it is not the case then you have to save your check box states at server side and use it. I think that is what @H77 was trying to say.

Comment: How is the ajax being called? Through form submit? If so, then you need to preventDefault the form submit event in order to stop the page from reloading.

Comment: `table.html("");` replaces your content every time you switch to a new page thereby clearing your checked data. So you need to save the content state (maybe the checkbox values or the entire content html) before switching to another table page. You can make use of the saved state next time you switch to that page. Or you could also just show/hide that table page instead of clearing it when switching.

Comment: @H77, then i will like to show/hide when filtering. How do i get this done?  I m actually using `table.html("")` to return the default items on the table if the input for searching is cleared or empty

Comment: @SandipGhosh, i don't call it through a form